# Spring MVC application not working

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

I am trying as explained [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-spring.html), but couldn't get the output that is shown for the second page. 
It redirects to the second page but doesn't print the text i entered, rather returns the empty page.
Any suggestions ? i am using spring framework 3.0.2.

**helloView.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>${helloMessage}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**nameView.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Name</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Enter your Name</h1>
       <spring:nestedPath path="name">
    <form action="" method="post">
        Name:
        <spring:bind path="value">
            <input type="text" name="${status.expression}" value="${status.value}">
        </spring:bind>
        <input type="submit" value="OK">
    </form>
</spring:nestedPath>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: My project structure]

Comment: Can you paste your jsp code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this bean class

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
```

This bean is responsible for automatically creating an URL mapping for all controllers registered in the file. It takes the fully-qualified class name of the controller (in our case, controller.HelloController) and strips the package name and Controller suffix, then uses the result as a URL mapping.